# Error [ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE] in IIS (DMZ Zone) in local is not error

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I tried to write the code to download the file.I have tested for local server is not error,
But production server (which iis in DMZ Zone).
I get an error as below.

**Message Error**

(might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error code: ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE)

```
                FileStream fs = null; 
                fs = File.Open(localPath, FileMode.Open); 
                byte[] btFile = new byte[fs.Length + 1]; 
                fs.Read(btFile, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length)); 
                fs.Close();  

                Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName); 
                Response.ContentType = "application/" + type; 

                Response.BinaryWrite(btFile); 
                Response.Flush(); 
                Response.Close();
```

What should I do to fix it..? Please advise me

Thank you

Comment: The "error" code is actually an HTTP status code of 320 which should be redirecting you to a new URL. You will want to look at the status code of the response and see if it is 200 (OK) and then try to write out a file. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error (**ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE**) while retrieving data from the database using the Entity Framework. On DEV server it worked fine, but on UAT it hanged and returned that error.

It turned out that the query was using dynamic predicate and that caused invoking the filter method from IEnumerable instead of IQueryable. It was visible on SQL Profiler. The query tried to fetch the whole data to the memory. Converting dynamic predicate to epression fixed the issue.

In general that error was caused by OutOfMemoryException on the server side and didn't occur on DEV because of database size. That could be a clue for you.